# django best practice for navbar across multiple pages

Tags: html, css, django, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

What is the best practice way of implementing multipage navbars in webpages using Django. To be more specific (since this is the technology I am using) a Bootstrap navbar.

Many tutorials motivate Django template inheritance by demonstrating an example of a page that inherits from a base page that contains the navbar.

To my mind this doesn't sound optimal since the navbar would be re-downloaded and re-rendered in the browser with every request, while the server will have to re-serve it.

On the other hand most Bootstrap tutorials assumes all the content in all the tabs of the navbar are in one webpage.

So my question is, is there a standard Django or Bootstrap functionality that allows one to implement this scenario in a more optimal way?

Answer (score 0):

you can use Django fragment caching and then your navbar will be rendered from the cache and not from the server.

```
{% load cache %}
{% cache 500 navbar%}
    .. navbar code here ..
{% endcache %}
```

you can refer to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/cache/#template-fragment-caching) for more option.